# selecting next todo item from child table

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I've a table with millions of records, relationship is one (object) to many (object_items).

**object_items:**

```
CREATE TABLE `object_items` (
  `item_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `object_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sequence` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uni_seq_object_id` (`sequence`,`object_id`),
  KEY `idx_object_id` (`object_id`),
  KEY `idx_seq` (`sequence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3408237 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

**Sample Data:**

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+
| item_name | object_id | sequence | completed | id   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+
| ABCD      |        10 |        1 |         1 |    1 |
| BCDE      |        10 |        2 |         1 |    2 |
| CDEF      |        10 |        3 |         1 |    3 |
| DEFG      |        10 |        4 |         0 |    4 |
| ABCD      |        11 |        1 |         1 |    5 |
| BCDE      |        11 |        2 |         1 |    6 |
| CDEF      |        11 |        3 |         0 |    7 |
| DEFG      |        11 |        4 |         0 |    8 |
| ABCD      |        12 |        1 |         1 |    9 |
| BCDE      |        12 |        2 |         1 |   10 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+
| item_name | object_id | sequence | completed | id   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+
| DEFG      |        10 |        4 |         0 |    4 |
| CDEF      |        11 |        3 |         0 |    7 |
+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+
```

**The Query I run:**

```
select
  a.*
from object_items a
where a.sequence = (
  select min(sequence)
  from object_items b
  where a.object_id = b.object_id
    and b.completed = 0
)
```

Which actually works but when I use limit, but if I run `count(*)` it just dies.

**Explaining the query:**

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref             | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL            | 3268598 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b     | NULL       | ref  | idx_object_id | idx_object_id | 4       | db.a.object_id  |      21 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-----------------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Is there a better way to get next TODO item that's not complete yet, by sequence, only for the objects those have at least one item to be done, with heavy database like this?

Thanks

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/180397/selecting-next-todo-item-from-child-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT object_id, MIN(sequence) AS sequence
    FROM object_items b
    WHERE b.completed = 0
    GROUP BY object_id
) AS m
INNER JOIN object_items a
  USING (object_id, sequence)
```

Add an index on the columns `(completed, object_id, sequence)` to optimize the subquery.

Add an index on the columns `(object_id, sequence)` to optimize the outer query.